# How can I safely catch an injured semi-domesticated pigeon?

Tags: safety, birds, injury, animal-handling

A pigeon in my neighbourhood has hurt her wing (see picture below). I would like to take her to a vet and see if they can treat her. If I try to catch her in a cage or a net, she will desperately try to escape by flapping her wings as a natural instinct. In the process, she may hurt herself even more, and there is a risk of the wing getting ripped off completely.

The pigeon regularly comes to my balcony to eat bird food (seeds, foodgrains, etc.) and drink water from a bowl that I place there. She usually comes alone, but quite often comes in a group with about 10 other pigeons. Hence, the pigeon is not exactly my "pet", but I am not a complete stranger either.

Is there anything I can do to help her?

[image: Pigeon]

Comment: This is my first question on this site. Please let me know if I should add more details.

Comment: You're very kind to care so much. It's a good question. Do you want to catch it if it's safe to do so and take it to the vet?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes, I would want to catch it and take it to the vet. The only reason I am not doing anything is I don't want to try something foolish and make it worse.

Comment: Does she eat from you when you offer her food?

Comment: Yes, she does. Some 6-8 pigeons come daily to drink the water and eat the food. She usually comes alone, but also in a group quite often.

Comment: Have you called the vet? There may be a sedative you can give her  - which might slow her down enough to catch her safely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64468/discussion-between-masked-man-and-yvette-colomb).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If she is too injured to escape the best method to catch her is to use a towel. You do not risk injuring her further as you would with a net - their wings and legs tend to get caught and tangled in the netting.

[image]

**Note: I am aware the bird in the picture is not a pigeon but the method is the same.**

Once you have the bird you can place her in a box and bring her to a wildlife rehab or local veterinarian for further guidance.

### IMPORTANT

When restraining a bird be sure to not apply too much pressure to the body, this will prevent the bird from breathing and could result in death. Their respiratory system is much more complicated and delicate than ours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a risk of her attacking me with her beak or claws if I try to catch her in this manner? I guess I could use some protective gear to guard against that. I was just wondering if I can do it myself and take her to the vet, or it would be a better idea to bring in a professional to catch her.

Comment: You can do it yourself, these birds tend to just flap around and dont try to bite. They submit once they feel like they cannot move any longer.

Comment: you can see on the picture how to grab and hold the bird,the hood over the birds head is there to make it dark so it dont move.

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to catch it in the dark, as many birds are completely blind at night; it doesn't need to be totally dark. Humans have better night vision than many types of birds, so at night one can simply grab the bird.

My sister has had several types of birds, and when they escaped from their cages it was often enough just to turn off the lights, take them from where they were, and put them back in the cage.